# Sorting arrays of objects using compareTo()

Tags: java, sorting

I may be making this a lot harder than it is...but my assignment was to create a showtimes class that implements Comparable. With this it constructs sort of a list of several different theatres w/ what movies are showing, with the times etc. Then I have to use the compareTo() method to sort it by first the cinema that it's showing in, and by the movie title. I have the following code...the confusion comes when I'm trying to output the sorted results. I have it to where it will output the - or + number from comparing the strings.

```
public class ShowTimeTest {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    ShowTime[] movieTimes= new ShowTime[20];
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //******************************************************
    //Instantiates 20 showtime objects
    //******************************************************



ShowTime cinemark1 = new ShowTime("Cinemark", "Lorde", "Friday @ 3:30", "Saturday @ 7:00", "Sunday @ 6:00","R", 1, 2);
ShowTime cinemark2 = new ShowTime("Amstar Cinemas", "Star Wars", "Thursday @ 12:00AM", "Monday @ 4:00PM", "Sunday @ 3:45PM","R", 1, 2);
ShowTime cinemark3 = new ShowTime("Fayette Movies", "Pokemon", "Friday @ 3:30", "Saturday @ 7:00", "Sunday @ 6:00","R", 1, 2);
ShowTime cinemark4 = new ShowTime("Dollar Theatre", "Reincarnated", "Friday @ 3:30", "Saturday @ 7:00", "Sunday @ 6:00","R", 1, 2);
ShowTime cinemark5 = new ShowTime("Rad Chads Cinemas", "Lorde", "Friday @        3:30",     "Saturday @ 7:00", "Sunday @ 6:00","R", 1, 2);
movieTimes[0] = cinemark1;
movieTimes[1] = cinemark2;
movieTimes[2] = cinemark3;
movieTimes[3] = cinemark4;
movieTimes[4] = cinemark5;

for(int i = 1; i < 5; i ++){
    System.out.println(movieTimes[i].compareTo(movieTimes[i-1]));

 }
}
}
```

contd...

```
public class ShowTime implements Comparable<ShowTime>{

public String name, title, rating, showTime1, showTime2, showTime3;
public double ticket, adultTicket;
public String[] times = new String[3];

public ShowTime(String theatreName, String movieTitle, String showTime1, String showTime2, String showTime3 , String movieRating, double childTicket, double aTicket)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
name = theatreName; 
title = movieTitle;
times[0] = showTime1;
times[1] = showTime2;
times[2] = showTime3;
rating = movieRating;
ticket = childTicket;
adultTicket = aTicket;
}
public String toString(){
    String out = "Theatre: ";
    out += name+ "  " + "Movie: " + title + " " + "Rating " + rating + " " + "ShowTimes " + times[0] + " " + times[1] + " " +  times[2]
            +  " " + "Adult Cost: " + adultTicket + " " + "Child Ticket: " +ticket;
    return out;
}
public int compareTo(ShowTime other) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //sorts the showtimes by theater(NAME) and movie(TITLE)
    int result;

    if(name.equals(((ShowTime)other).name)){
        result = title.compareTo(((ShowTime)other).title);
    }

    else{
        result = name.compareTo(((ShowTime)other).name);
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: You're almost done--now just sort!

Comment: Thanks! it's nice to hear I'm actually doing something right. I'm just so lost when it comes to sorting the darn thing, its like I spent all my brain power doing the above

Comment: you will get a `NullPointerException` if you call `Arrays.sort(movieTimes);` since you initialized only 5 elements but you've allocated 20.

Comment: Well the assignment was to make 20, I only made 5 to make sure I had everything working appropriately before making all 20

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of making your class implement the `Comparable` interface was so that you could sort an array of `ShowTime`s.  You've done all the hard work.  Now just apply [Arrays.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29), sit back, and enjoy the movies.

Since this is an educational show, let me be 100% pellucidly clear: You already have yourself an `Object[]`  whose elements implement `Comparable`, namely `movieTimes`.  So, all you need to do is add the single line:

```
Arrays.sort(movieTimes);
```

Note that this will fail until you fill up your theater with 20 movies (or declare it as a miniplex that holds only 5 movies).

Comment: will we get popcorn, too ?

Comment: I was writing an answer but I don't really think anything else needs to be said. Just call sort.

Comment: Thanks! That's a real help, I'm struggling to apply it though because there's so many to do with arrays of objects. I tend to make these small things way harder than they are, it just loses me because I have to sort by the cinema (Name) AND the movie, I just tried: sort(movieTimes, 0, 5); at i get syntax error saying sort is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class:

```
List<ShowTime> list = Arrays.asList(array);
Collections.sort(list);
movieTimes = list.toArray();
```

Comment: He could use better `Arrays.sort(array)`

Comment: Yeah, didn't see that answer at the time.